# Spark 1.6 - Overwrite directory with avro files failing using dataframes

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-avro, apache-spark-1.6

I have a directory in HDFS which contains avro files. While I try to overwrite the directory with dataframe it fails.
Syntax: avroData_df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("")
The error is:
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://nameservice1//part-r-00000-bca9a5b6-5e12-45c1-a877-b0f6d6cc8cd3.avro

It somehow seems to be considering the avro files as well while overwriting.

Can we do this using Spark 1.6 at all?